# subtracting identical object values javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint-config-airbnb

What is the best way to subtract or add values ​​from identical objects?

```
const obj1 = {
  1: 10,
  2: 10,
  3: 10,
  4: 10,
};

const obj2 = {
  1: 30,
  2: 30,
  3: 30,
  4: 30,
};

const result = obj2 - obj1;

console.log(result);

/* the expected output is: 
{
    1:20,
    2: 20,
    3: 20,
    4: 20,
};
*/
```

ESLint points out that using for in to add values ​​is not a good practice and the log is "guard-for-in: The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.
"

```
for (const p in obj2) {
  newObj[p] = obj2[p] - obj1[p];
}
console.log(newObj);
```

Doing with for in I also had problems returning unwanted values ​​like `$init":0` when using an array of objects.

Comment: _"the ESLint is not as good practice"_ what do you mean?

Comment: `$init` so what library/framework you are using that is adding properties to your objects?

Comment: " "the ESLint is not as good practice" what do you mean? "   sorry i'll fix the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESLint's warning means that with `in` you will also iterate properties on the object's prototype chain, not only the properties owned by the object.

You could use `Object.entries` which only visits owned properties, and `Object.fromEntries` to build the result:

```js
const obj1 = { 1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10 };
const obj2 = { 1: 30, 2: 30, 3: 30, 4: 30 };
const obj3 = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj2).map( ([k, v]) => [k, v - obj1[k]] )
);
console.log(obj3);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), which provides the object's own property names and will not find keys from the prototype chain.

```js
const obj1 = {
  1: 10,
  2: 10,
  3: 10,
  4: 10,
};

const obj2 = {
  1: 30,
  2: 30,
  3: 30,
  4: 30,
};
const obj3 = Object.keys(obj2)
    .reduce((acc,curr)=>(acc[curr]=obj2[curr]-obj1[curr],acc),{});
console.log(obj3);
```

ESLint is pointing out the fact that you are not using [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to make sure you are only looping over keys of the object itself and not inherited ones.

```
for (const p in obj2) {
  if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(p))
       newObj[p] = obj2[p] - obj1[p];
}
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: ... and if ESLint is complaning about `obj2.hasOwnProperty()` because of a [`no-prototype-builtins`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins) rule, you can do `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj2, p)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj1 = {
  1: 10,
  2: 10,
  3: 10,
  4: 10,
};

const obj2 = {
  1: 30,
  2: 30,
  3: 30,
  4: 30,
};

const diff = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const result = Object.assign({}, obj1);
  Object.keys(result).forEach((key) => {
    result[key] -= obj2[key];
  });
  return result;
}

const result = diff(obj2, obj1);

console.log(result);
```