# subtracting identical object values typescript

Tags: typescript

I would to know how to subtract identical object values in typescript using Generics and type-safe, based on: [subtracting identical object values javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802253/subtracting-identical-object-values-javascript)

```
    const subtractObjects = <T extends Record<String, number>>(objA: T, objB: T): T =>
      Object.keys(objA).reduce((a, k) => {
        a[k] = objA[k] - objB[k];
        return a;
      }, {});
```

I receive the error:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, number>'.
```

Comment: What is `removeNullObjectValues()`?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wX79QW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: What you are doing is not safe; there are types that extend `SimpleObject` whose properties are narrower than `number`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOJvRW).  You cannot claim that `objA[k] - objB[k]` will be a valid property value for `T`.  You should probably switch to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL4Y2m) where only the keys are generic and the value is always of type `number`. Does that make sense and work for you? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: work as charm! please, go ahead and share this code as the answer! [this link](https://tsplay.dev/mL4Y2m). I realize I don't need the interface "SimpleObject" at all or could use something like "Record<string, number>". You can refer to it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Record<string, number>`, it doesn't necessarily mean that every property of `T` will have a value type that's exactly `number`.  It could well be something that `extends number`, such as a numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `123` or a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such types like `0 | 1`.  (See
[Why can't I return a generic 'T' to satisfy a Partial<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46980763/2887218) for a related discussion.)  For example:

```
type Money = {
  denomination: 1 | 5 | 10 | 20 | 50 | 100
}
const twenty: Money = { denomination: 20 };
const one: Money = { denomination: 1 };
const nineteen = subtractObjects<Money>(twenty, one);
/* const nineteen: Money */
console.log(nineteen.denomination) // 1 | 5 | 10 | 20 | 50 | 100 at compile time
// but 19 at runtime
```

Here, the type `Money` has a single known property `denomination` whose value must be one of a particular set of numbers.  And since `Money extends Record<string, number>`, you are allowed to pass two `Money`s into `subtractObjects()`.  And according to the call signature for `subtractObjects()`, that means a `Money` will come out.  The compiler says that `nineteen` is valid `Money`.  But if you check at runtime, its `denomination` property is *not* one of the allowed values.  You've accidentally produced counterfeit currency.

If it's not clear from that code example why counterfeit currency is a problem, then note that once you have a situation where the compiler is mistaken about the type of a value, it can lead to runtime errors:

```
function moneyName(m: Money) {
  return {
    1: "One",
    5: "Five",
    10: "Ten",
    20: "Twenty",
    50: "Fifty",
    100: "One Hundred"
  }[m.denomination]
}
console.log(moneyName(one).toUpperCase()) // ONE
console.log(moneyName(twenty).toUpperCase()) // TWENTY
console.log(moneyName(nineteen).toUpperCase()) //  RUNTIME ERROR! undefined
```

Anyway that means you cannot be sure that `subtractObjects()` will produce a valid `T` output.  The error message `'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, number>'` is saying that the output type of `reduce()` is not known to be assignable to whatever `T` will turn out to be, and that even though it will produce a `Record<string, number>`, not every `Record<string, number>` will work for every `T`.

---

In order to make this type safe, I'd say that you should change `subtractObjects()` to be generic in the set of *keys* `K` of the `objA` and `objB` inputs.  And `objA`, `objB`, and the output type will all be of type `Record<K, number>`.  So there's no way for the input type to have properties narrower than `number`.  It could look like this:

```
const subtractObjects = <K extends string>(
  objA: Record<K, number>,
  objB: Record<K, number>
) =>
  (Object.keys(objA) as K[]).reduce((a, k) => {
    a[k] = objA[k] - objB[k];
    return a;
  }, {} as { [P in K]: number });
```

This compiles with no error.

Here we've had to make a few [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  One is that we are assuming that `Object.keys(objA)` will produce an array of type `K[]`. It's technically true that `Object.keys(objA)` might produce more keys than the compiler knows about (See [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174/2887218) for more information) but we're making this simplifying assumption here.  You can always revisit that assumption if it turns out that it causes trouble.

Another is that we are claiming that the initial empty `{}` object in `reduce()` is already of type `Record<K, number>` (equivalent to `{[P in K]: number}`, which will turn out to display the type more nicely than `Record<K, number>`).  This is, of course, not true.  But when `reduce()` is done running then the object will no longer be empty and the output will be of type `Record<K, number>`, so the assertion is mostly harmless.

Okay, let's see it in action:

```
const nineteen = subtractObjects(twenty, one);
/* const nineteen: { denomination: number; } */
console.log(nineteen.denomination) // number at compile time, 
// 19 at runtime, no problem now!
```

Now the value `nineteen` is no longer considered to be of type `Money`.  The compiler says it's of type `{denomination: number}`, so the fact that `nineteen.denomination === 19` is fine; no fraud is being committed because nobody is claiming that `nineteen` is `Money`.

And so now you'll get a helpful compiler error if you try to hand someone phony currency:

```
moneyName(nineteen).toUpperCase()
// -----> ~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '{ denomination: number; }' is not 
// assignable to parameter of type 'Money'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJKiSwLIDyATgJYDmeJpS8A9sFAC5JQBXAEY9aCHtSEArCPB5QkAXiQAeACpIIADx4RgAEwUAlWR1r6VvBsEYAaMgLBCItAHyuAFB2kBBAFxIavbeUgBCAWoAlBFKrqxsSJIycgB0ANYQAJ5QXr6RKbQQ+gKIHh4g9mmRsSyECQkgANppALpKSCE+zW0AtB3Sod0A3PH1hTwCtMBIICN19QC+9rgLkXMJPJkwyACyXFntBPMJ+nocYPSgPPRcAQCMSAA+SACsT0h3AAzvAEzfzy9-h9Pp9RgtRpxuHweAB3PSbAJ7YAHZS4JCnYDnS4ga63JB-JALdZsSG8DrIxH7TKHdFnC5XG7Ae6E4mkUl8YCXCC6PTtQQiMRyJKyeQqJFZTyw+GZYLItYQrhQDgYCApDAcRgeTnInnAFIYrEMrjVAD0Jo+7zezy+vyBgPeX2+OPY5xg9BVSGukHsQgEfDuAE4ZnxaAJgF6IERRgAzMNyRlIMBUgBy4AgHjAlORmWqR3qSHGk2mefzHwCACJqMjy7ZRgkXhWAGL0ABuEBrdbYXwraj0HeO9T+Pbh4cy-dLr0+Tfo0c249LjorVeQAAkw-pCvpy52Fo0wPq6djccAWmCFdxlar1Zqk9nU5AvHKUjwOABVGDbWgAYRAUHTkVNc1qGTABRc8lRVNUNQzFM0w8KVR3yF930-H8-w8ACkDNQIAHUQOTNQAE1RlEakSwSUlLygm9YIfbVuQgPQkLfD8XDQ-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-W4F48rZEkDXAxN23D3d33Hmfq4U8Bw88GL0M6DzMySzH1058WNQ38OPl4CwMJxVxfrp34MT5iULYjuMM4tQ8II4intoMj9L7uuaLvODJc5kfWO-cfMOwzhVfdO6XBN2hO2wnoL8vq-r4v6aAD8H8fh+z-NHxaEYRx4Q6aNPS2ZAAHI0RlzxgrAWhJ-7nQUJiPgv4oBMFAEIdWhs4BiEgLoJWHAf7PQAW9f+KRVLoB4JpbSukfY1wgleaCDN5YNybtZFItl7IGEUspFyVdWAeSIB5IAA)